# How to get the rows with Max value in Spark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a dataframe (df1) with the following details

```
| Date      |High|Low |
| --------  |----|----|
| 2021-01-23| 89 | 43 |
| 2021-02-09| 90 | 54 |
|2009-09-19 | 96 | 50 |
```

I then apply aggregate functions to the High

```
df1.agg({'High':'max'}).show()
```

This will give me:

```
| max(High)|
| -------- |
|    96    |
```

How can I apply filter or other methods so that I can get the other columns that is within the same row as max(High) to show together with aggregated results?

My desired outcome is -

```
| Date     | High | Low  |
| -------- | ---- |------|
|2009-09-19| 96   | 50   |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily to did by extracting the `MAX` High value and finally applying a `filter` against the value on the entire Dataframe

#### Data Preparation

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Date':['2021-01-23','2021-02-09','2009-09-19'],
        'High':[89,90,96],
        'Low':[43,54,50]
})

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(df)

sparkDF.show()

+----------+----+---+
|      Date|High|Low|
+----------+----+---+
|2021-01-23|  89| 43|
|2021-02-09|  90| 54|
|2009-09-19|  96| 50|
+----------+----+---+
```

#### Filter

```
max_high = sparkDF.select(F.max(F.col('High')).alias('High')).collect()[0]['High']

>>> 96

sparkDF.filter(F.col('High') == max_high).orderBy(F.col('Date').desc()).limit(1).show()

+----------+----+---+
|      Date|High|Low|
+----------+----+---+
|2009-09-19|  96| 50|
+----------+----+---+
```

Comment: Note this can return more than one row in case multiple rows share the same max value. This might or might not be desired depending on your use case.

Comment: That's a valid case , but that primarily depends on the underlying data. I have updated the answer to show the latest row with max value

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this might be by using the pyspark `max_by` function.

```
d = [
    {"Date": "2021-01-23", "High": 89, "Low": 43},
    {"Date": "2021-02-09", "High": 90, "Low": 54},
    {"Date": "2009-09-19", "High": 96, "Low": 50},
]

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(d)
df1.show()

+----------+----+---+
|      Date|High|Low|
+----------+----+---+
|2021-01-23|  89| 43|
|2021-02-09|  90| 54|
|2009-09-19|  96| 50|
+----------+----+---+
```

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df1.agg(
    F.max_by("Date", "High").alias("Date"),
    F.max("High").alias("High"),
    F.max_by("Low", "High").alias("Low"),
).show()

+----------+----+---+
|      Date|High|Low|
+----------+----+---+
|2009-09-19|  96| 50|
+----------+----+---+
```